# Xamarin.Forms find container listview from within a data template

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView, on one of my Views which contains a collection of data templates I build up from a custom implementation on the DataTemplateSelector.

The implementation is vary simple, a JSON string denotes the type of control I need to render, and I convert the object to the necessary type (stating this for clarity).

My problem, and I've been struggling with this for the last day or so, is to get a handle on the ListView from within one of these data templates; I need this, to iterate each of the data templates, in search of a matching "KEY" associated with some data contained in each of these "entites". The particulars of the use case is not relevant, unfortunately, I do not seem to be able to get an instance of the ListView, from, let's say ActionA or ActionZ.

Is there a way to get an instance of a data template's container through code behind?

Take into account, the following code is an extract from an application that uses Prism MVVM, and all code logic is developed in the ViewModel.

The ListView looks something like this (code omitted for brevity):

```
<ListView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ColorGreyDark}"
            x:Name="TemplSelector"
            AutomationId="TemplSelector"
            SeparatorVisibility="None" 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource QuestionnaireDataTemplateSelector}" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionnaireList}" 
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" HasUnevenRows="true">
    <ListView.Footer>
        <!-- Hosts an indicator and a button -->
    </ListView.Footer>
</ListView>
```

The ItemTemplate, is a static resource collection, which then gets allocated to associated properties on the custom data template selector:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converters:InverseBooleanConverter x:Key="inverseBooleanConverter" />
        <DataTemplate x:Key="checkbox">
            <ViewCell>
                <templates:CheckBoxActionView />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="dropDown">
            <ViewCell>
                <templates:DropDownActionView />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="freeText">
            <ViewCell>
                <templates:FreeTextActionView />
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>

        <local:QuestionnaireDataTemplateSelector x:Key="QuestionnaireDataTemplateSelector" 
                                                 Checkbox="{StaticResource checkbox}" 
                                                 DropDown="{StaticResource dropDown}" 
                                                 FreeText="{StaticResource freeText}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

The data template selector code behind would look something like this:

```
public class QuestionnaireDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate Checkbox { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate DropDown { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate FreeText { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        if (typeof(CheckBoxAction) == item.GetType())
        {
            return Checkbox;
        }
        else if (typeof(DropDownAction) == item.GetType())
        {
            return DropDown;
        }
        else if (typeof(FreeTextAction) == item.GetType())
        {
            return FreeText;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Each `{Name}Action` class in the code above, is a StackLayout XAML with associated ViewModel.

My first price was to try and grab the ItemsSource from the ListView control, let's say, in the "checkbox" action's ViewModel, but it seems that there is no way to get a reference in the CheckboxAction view model to the ListView, so that I can grab the ItemsSource.

If I can just get the ListView instance, I can do what I need to do, but I cannot find any information on the net regards this.

Is it possible, and if so, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I went the EventAggregator route in Prism 6+.